# How to do casting with respect to double and int

Tags: java

I have two variables:

```
double d1 = 15.20;
 int i1 = 10;
```

I want to divide i1 by 100 so I can get 0.1 and then I want to add in d1.

Here are the things I tried

`i1 = i1/100  result is 0`

`i1 = (int) ((double)i1/100); result is 0`

I tried a couple of more same kind of thing but either I am getting result 0 or 2.

Can anybody please show me how to do the operation with casting w.r.t double and int. I am very new in java

Comment: You do know that an int variable can only contain integer values, right?

Comment: It's no good casting if you then immediately assign the result back to an int :/

Comment: what do you think the int value of `0.1` would be?

Comment: @Eran Yes I know that, Thats what I am asking how to use operator on cross data type.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes I agree therefore I tried the second code and couple of other lines, But didn't work.

Comment: Unless you think that `0.1` will round up to `1` I do not follow your thinking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
i1 = (int) ((double)i1/100);
```

Since `i1` is an `integer`, no matter whatever the result on right hand side it converts/rounds to integer. Hence your result `0.1` converting back to `0`.

Store it in a `double` to retain the `double` result.

```
double result = ((double)i1/100);
```

Or even better, convert any of the operands to `double` to tell that result should be a `double` so that you can avoid casting completely.

```
 double result = i1/100.0;
```

Comment: Thanks this is working. One quick question why you are focusing to avoid casting. Is any harm of doing casting. I mean operation point of view

Comment: @David There is no harm doing that but you can clearly don't need it as the language already gave you an easy choice. You can do it if you have to.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

remember that dividing ints produce an integer too...
if you want to avoid casting then it will be ok to declare the 100 as 100.0 (a literal double), that operation will promote the variable i1 into a double and the result will produce a double too...  `i1 / 100.0;`

the rest is similar to other answers

```
double d1 = 15.20;
int i1 = 10;

d1 += i1 / 100.0;
System.out.println(d1);
```

Answer (score 1):

int/int results in an int. if you mix types, then you have a dobule.

so, for example, just divide by a double. no need to complicate formula:

```
double result = d1 + i1/100.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read a tutorial on the different data types and how they relate to each other, plus casting in general (It can be really confusing when you are just getting started, but you'll learn it quickly ;)).

Your specific problem can be solved by changing the type of *i1* to **double** as integers can only contain whole numbers.

So then if you do:

```
double d1 = 15.2;
double i1 = 10.;

// short version
d1 += i1 / 100; // a += b is short for a = a + b
System.out.println(d1); //will print "15.3"

// extensive version
i1 = i1 / 100; // assigns the value 0.1 ti i1
d1 = d1 + i1;
System.out.println(d1); //will also print "15.3"
```

There are loads and loads of great tutorials on this topic on the internet, consider picking a few out and start learnng. ;)

Cheers